# how to create custom type error on constraint violation

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I have a class instance that has some relatively unintuitive constraints. This results in unreadable error messages if this constraint is violated. What I would like to do is provide a custom type error which explains the constraint in a human readable way. I have looked [here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/proposal/custom-type-errors) which seems close to what I want. However the TypeError I want to generate is based on a constraint violation and not on the instance declaration.

Here is example code of what I would like to achieve:

```
data Foo (n :: Nat) = Foo

instance
  (TypeError (Text "Missing KnownNat constraint")) 
  => Eq (Foo n) where (==) = undefined

instance
  (KnownNat n) 
  => Eq (Foo n) where (==) _ _ = True
```

I don't particularly need two instance declaration. If there is some other way to do it I'm fine with it as well.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, in general. GHC works under an open world assumption so to support incremental compilation. This would entail to commit to "no instance exists" on a local basis, which copes with that. I'd be happy to be proven wrong on this, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Csongor Kiss has come up with a technique that can sometimes improve error messages in these cases, though it can't give custom type errors. There are also situations where it will make type errors *less* useful, so some judgement and care is required. His technique needs a minor tweak to work here.

```
eqFoo
  :: KnownNat n
  => Foo n -> Foo n -> Bool
eqFoo _ _ = True

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-}
    Eq (Foo 0) where
  (==) = eqFoo

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}
    KnownNat n => Eq (Foo n) where
  (==) = eqFoo
```

Now GHC can't reduce the `Eq (Foo n)` constraint to `KnownNat n` until it knows what `n` is. So you'll get an error saying that it couldn't resolve the instance for `Eq (Foo n)` rather than one about `KnownNat`. In this case, that seems strictly worse, but maybe in your real code it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

While the following won't work for all constraints. In the case that your constraint operates on a finite number of types you can do something like the following:

```
class Bar a where
  baz :: a -> a

data Foo (n :: Nat) = Foo deriving Show

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Bar (Foo 0) where
  baz = id

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Bar (Foo 1) where
  baz = id

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (TypeError (Text "N is greater then 1")) => Bar (Foo a) where
  baz = undefined

r1 = baz (Foo :: Foo 0) -- succeeds
r2 = baz (Foo :: Foo 1) -- succeeds
r3 = baz (Foo :: Foo 2) -- fails with custom type error
```

I will keep this question open until someone comes along that either gives a general solution or tells us this isn't possible with some good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will not work for arbitrary constraints, but since the question seems to be dealing with `Nat`s we can have a general solution for this problem. What we want is the `TypeError` at the type level, rather than at the constraint level, like it was suggested in the suggested solution by @John Smith:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

class Bar a where
  baz :: a -> a

data Foo (n :: Nat) = Foo deriving Show

type family ReportNotInRange (n :: Nat) (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) xAbove yBelow :: Bool where
  ReportNotInRange n x y 'True  'True = 'True
  ReportNotInRange n x y 'False 'True =
    TypeError ('Text "Value " :<>: ShowType n :<>: 'Text " is below the expected " :<>: ShowType x)
  ReportNotInRange n x y xAbove 'False =
    TypeError ('Text "Value " :<>: ShowType n :<>: 'Text " is above the expected " :<>: ShowType y)

type family InRange n x y :: Bool where
  InRange n x y = ReportNotInRange n x y (x <=? n) (n <=? y)

instance (KnownNat n, InRange n 1 2 ~ 'True) => Bar (Foo n) where
  baz = id

r1 = baz (Foo :: Foo 0) -- fails with custom type error
r2 = baz (Foo :: Foo 1) -- succeeds
r3 = baz (Foo :: Foo 2) -- succeeds
r4 = baz (Foo :: Foo 3) -- fails with custom type error
```

Above code gives us a very nice descriptive compilation errors and we didn't need to use overlapping instances:

```
how-to-create-custom-type-error-on-constraint-violation.hs:37:6-23: error: …
    • Value 0 is below the expected 1
    • In the expression: baz (Foo :: Foo 0)
      In an equation for ‘r1’: r1 = baz (Foo :: Foo 0)
   |
how-to-create-custom-type-error-on-constraint-violation.hs:40:6-23: error: …
    • Value 3 is above the expected 2
    • In the expression: baz (Foo :: Foo 3)
      In an equation for ‘r4’: r4 = baz (Foo :: Foo 3)
   |
Compilation failed.
```